# How to get a localized, pluralized date part?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-intl

Curious how I can get a localized, plural part of any date.

e.g "Octobers, Novembers" or "Mondays, Tuesdays"

Comment: IMO, there is no inbuilt way of doing it. If you have limited strings like this, you can use Google Translate and thereafter use intl package of flutter to use it in the app.